# Android 5 webview native navigation on m.youtube.com is broken by javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, youtube

I noticed that on the page http://m.youtube.com method [WebView.goBack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goBack()) doesn't work after you inject any javascript. This happens only on Android 5.0+.

I wrote a test app which contains only of a WebView (code is below). 
The steps are the following:
1. I load m.youtube.com into webview programmatically.
2. I press on any video and navigate to another youtube page.
3. I press hardware "Back" button, which calls WebView.goBack() method.
I expect to go back to m.youtube.com, but nothing happens.

Can anybody explain why this happens (I think this is because webview's native navigation is also implemented with javascript, and those scripts are interracting in some strange way, but I can't imagine what exactly happens because my script is empty) and how to work around this?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private WebView  mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com");
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

private class MyClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:;");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As we all know (from android developers blog and documetation) we should no longer use `WebView.loadUrl` to run javascript's script on API >= 19 ...

Comment: what about: `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (!url.startsWith("javascript")) {
                        final String script = ";";
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                            view.loadUrl("javascript:" + script);
                        else
                            view.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
                    }
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }`

Comment: @Selvin thank you, I really missed that method. This solved the problem!